# PCMPESTRM is not working when explicit length is 1

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, gnu-assembler

I want to compare a string with length (max = 15) to check characters are in Range 'A' to 'Z' in assembly language. I am using PCMPESTRM instruction to perform this operation. My implementation(GAS) is as follows:

```
movq        $0x5A41,     %r12                # A: 0x41, Z: 0x5A --> defining Range
movq        %r12,        %xmm12              # Storing the result to SSE register
movq        %rdx,        %rax                # rdx: length of the string, storing to rax
pcmpestrm   $0x44,       %xmm10,    %xmm12   # %xmm10: actual string
```

I can see the comparison result %xmm0.
This instruction is working for length 2-15. But for specifically length 1, the value of %xmm0 doesn't change.

- Why it's not working for length 1?
- Is There anything I missed in my implementation?

Comment: I am a little puzzled, you set `r12` to 2 bytes but then say it has length 1?

Comment: Seems to work if I set the `eax` to `2` since that is the length of the range input which is independent of the string length.

Comment: r12 is used temporarily to prepare the control byte , how PCMPESTRM should behave. 
here 
%xmm10: 'Once Upon'
%xmm12: 'ZA'
xmm12 is definning the range.

Comment: My point is your `ZA` is 2 bytes so `eax` must be 2, no matter what your string length is.

Comment: Ah! ...... I missed that... let me check.. I will let you know soon!

Comment: Yesssss! It just worked like a charm! you saved my day.... Jester...